# Sorting List of Class by indexof array

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have array list with long ids

```
Arrays.asList(12, 34, 54, 22, 33);
```

I have an Object with `OwnerClass(String description, long id);`

I want to sort the `List<OwnerClass>` by the index of id in my array list.. so if id is 12 it will be the first and if id is 33 it will be the last.. if the id is not found in the array then put it in the last..

Comment: `Collections.sort(ownerClassList, Comperator.comparingInt(o -> longList.indexOf(o.getId()));` You might need to check the result of index of and replace it with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn can we close this question as such questions already has answer here multiple times.

Comment: If you find the duplicate, yes. Also the reason I use a comment. Not worth the time to explain how I know what each piece does and how it relates to the question.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn may be shortened to `ownerClassList.sort(Comperator.comparingInt(o -> longList.indexOf(o.getId()));`

Comment: Why is this being upvoted when there is no attempt from OP to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work

```
 final var integers = Arrays.asList(12, 34, 54, 22, 33);

 final var ownerClasses = Arrays.asList(new OwnerClass("", 33), new OwnerClass("", 54), new OwnerClass("", 34), new OwnerClass("", 22), new OwnerClass("", 12));

 ownerClasses.sort(Comparator.comparing(ownerClass -> {var index = integers.indexOf(ownerClass.id); return index != -1 ? index : Integer.MAX_VALUE;}));
```

Result

```
[OwnerClass(description=, id=12), OwnerClass(description=, id=34), OwnerClass(description=, id=54), OwnerClass(description=, id=22), OwnerClass(description=, id=33),
OwnerClass(description=,  id=100)]
```